# Testing memory on NVidia 660 graphics card

Tags: memory, nvidia-graphics-card, memtest

Is there a tool for testing the memory on my GTX 660 VGA?

I am looking for something like the memory test tools for my "normal" RAM where I can run several test patterns (quick test, comprehensive tests, etc.).

As I understand [How to test video card memory](https://superuser.com/questions/133844/how-to-test-video-card-memory) the answers there refer to tools that test the VGA in general, not specifically the VRAM. Or am i wrong on this?

Comment: I don't know if you get direct DMA access to the VRAM (thats why I am not posting as a answer), If that is true you would have to use a tool that exercises the card as a whole instead of the memory.

Comment: Is that so? Is it not the way you can write programs for modern GPUs as you write programs for CPUs. I am not an expert on this, but I'd expect that you can arbitrary test code. Correct me if I am wrong. Also I'd expect the VGA has a memory test routine you can trigger via an API (again, just a guess).

Comment: Yes but that test routineis running on the GPU, and that is what you said you do not want to do. If you are fine with the GPU testing the VRAM use any of the answers posted in the question you link to, like the "Video Memory Stress".

Comment: OK, here is my understanding. Normal test programs for VGAs (I have seen) draw a lot of graphics, images etc. They ask you whether you see a certain pattern correctly or draw millions of primitives and benchmark the time. But what if I see sometimes some spikes or artifacts? Can be the cable, the monitor, or some other stuff. I want to run a test and say "test the video memory, and only the memory" and give me a result on this. That's what I have not seen in such programs. If there is one with such an option, that's the answer (if working with NVidia cards, of course).