# How to check RAM on nVidia graphics card?

Tags: windows-8.1, hardware-failure, nvidia-geforce

How to check RAM on nVidia graphics card?

I am experiencing some errors and would like to check my video card memory. I downloaded cuda-memcheck, but looks like it is not memory check, but memory usage check for application developers.

I need to check hardware, not software.

Is it possible?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://superuser.com/questions/133844/how-to-test-video-card-memory Or this: http://superuser.com/questions/456435/how-can-i-test-my-gpu-memory-ram

Answer (score 1):

Simtk has a bunch of tools for checking ram. It requires a login, and its CLI only (and read the readme for instructions). In your case [memtestG80 or memtest cuda](https://simtk.org/home/memtest/) would both be options. While it won't let you test *all* your memory (and it tests just 128 by default), you can tweak it to test as much of it as possible.

[image]